# Fill in gap with prior record value having a populated quantity LIMIT: no analytics can be used

Tags: sql, hana, hana-graphical-calculation-view

Assume data with structure like this: [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c0b5ea7b21784c988ac10eea031a345b)

```
WITH CAL AS(
SELECT 2022 YR, '01' PERIOD UNION ALL
SELECT 2022 YR, '02' PERIOD UNION ALL
SELECT 2022 YR, '03' PERIOD UNION ALL
SELECT 2022 YR, '04' PERIOD UNION ALL
SELECT 2022 YR, '05' PERIOD UNION ALL
SELECT 2022 YR, '06' PERIOD UNION ALL
SELECT 2022 YR, '07' PERIOD UNION ALL
SELECT 2022 YR, '08' PERIOD UNION ALL
SELECT 2022 YR, '09' PERIOD UNION ALL
SELECT 2022 YR, '10' PERIOD UNION ALL
SELECT 2022 YR, '11' PERIOD UNION ALL
SELECT 2022 YR, '12' PERIOD ),
Data AS (
SELECT 2022 YR, '01' PERIOD, 10 qty UNION ALL
SELECT 2022 YR, '02' PERIOD, 5 qty UNION ALL
SELECT 2022 YR, '04' PERIOD, 10 qty UNION ALL
SELECT 2022 YR, '05' PERIOD, 7 qty UNION ALL
SELECT 2022 YR, '09' PERIOD, 1 qty)

SELECT * 
FROM CAL A
LEFT JOIN data B
 on A.YR = B.YR
 and A.Period = B.Period
WHERE A.Period <10 and A.YR = 2022
ORDER by A.period
```

Giving us:

```
+------+--------+------+--------+-----+
|  YR  | PERIOD |  YR  | PERIOD | qty |
+------+--------+------+--------+-----+
| 2022 |     01 | 2022 |     01 |  10 |
| 2022 |     02 | 2022 |     02 |   5 |
| 2022 |     03 |      |        |     |
| 2022 |     04 | 2022 |     04 |  10 |
| 2022 |     05 | 2022 |     05 |   7 |
| 2022 |     06 |      |        |     |
| 2022 |     07 |      |        |     |
| 2022 |     08 |      |        |     |
| 2022 |     09 | 2022 |     09 |   1 |
+------+--------+------+--------+-----+
```

With Expected result of:

```
+------+--------+------+--------+-----+
|  YR  | PERIOD |  YR  | PERIOD | qty |
+------+--------+------+--------+-----+
| 2022 |     01 | 2022 |     01 |  10 |
| 2022 |     02 | 2022 |     02 |   5 |
| 2022 |     03 | 2022 |     03 |   5 | -- SQL derives
| 2022 |     04 | 2022 |     04 |  10 |
| 2022 |     05 | 2022 |     05 |   7 | 
| 2022 |     06 | 2022 |     06 |   7 | -- SQL derives
| 2022 |     07 | 2022 |     07 |   7 | -- SQL derives
| 2022 |     08 | 2022 |     08 |   7 | -- SQL derives
| 2022 |     09 | 2022 |     09 |   1 |
+------+--------+------+--------+-----+
```

QUESTION:
How would one go about filling in the gaps in period 03, 06, 07, 08 with a record quantity referencing the nearest earlier period/year.  Note example is limited to a year, but gap could be on period 01 of 2022 and we would need to return 2021 period 12 quantity if populated or keep going back until quantity is found, or no such record exists.

LIMITS:

- I am unable  to use table value functions. (No lateral, no Cross Apply)
- I'm unable to use analytics (no lead/lag)
- correlated subqueries are iffy.

Why the limits?  this must be done in a HANA graphical calculation view.  Which supports neither of those concepts. I've not done enough to know how to do a correlated subquery at this time to know if it's possible.

- I can create any number of inline views or materialized datasets needed.

STATISTICS:

- this table has over a million rows and grows at a rate of product*location*periods*years.  so if you have 1000*20*12*6=1.4 mil+ in 6 years with just 20 locations and 1000 products...
- each product inventory **may** be recorded at at the end of a month for a given location. (no activity for product/location, no record hence a gap.  Silly mainframe save storage technique used in a RDBMS...  I mean how do I know the system just didn't error on inserting the record for that material; or omit it for some reason... )
- In the cases where it is not recorded, we need to fill in the gap.  The example provided is broken down to the bear bones without location and material as I do not believe it is not salient to a solution.

ISSUE:

- I'll need to convert the SQL to a "HANA Graphical calculation view"
- Yes, I know I could create a SQL Script to do this.  This is not allowed.
- Yes, I know I could create a table function to do this.  This is not allowed.
- This must be accomplished though Graphical calculation view which supports basic SQL functions
- BASIC Joins (INNER, OUTER, FULL OUTER, Cross), filters, aggregation, a basic rank at a significant performance impact if all records are evaluated. (few other things)  but not window functions, not cross Join, lateral...
- as to why it has to do with maintenance and staffing. The staffed area is a reporting area who uses tools to create views used in universes. The area wishes to keep all Scripts out of use to keep cost for employees lower as SQL knowledge wouldn’t be required for future staff positions, though it helps!

For those familiar this issue is sourced from MBEWH table in an ECC implementation

Comment: The "ISSUE" section demands an answer to the "WHY?" question for each of the listed limitations. The option to use SQLScript/table functions in calculation views was specifically built into HANA to address complex use cases, that are hard or inefficient to address in graphical calc. views. Excluding these options from possible solutions likely yield a sub-optimal solution.

Comment: No disagreement here.  It a constraint I am under for maintenance purposes as the customer has no one who can support “sql” in this fashion. I have pointed out the most optimal solution would likely be a table script creating a table value function . I can/have completed scripts producing the desired results but struggle with doing this handcuffed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with graphical calculation views in SAP HANA.

It's not pretty and probably not very efficient, though.
Whether or not the persons that are supposedly able to maintain graphical calc. views but not SQL statement will be able to successfully maintain this is rather questionable.

First, the approach in SQL, so that the approach becomes clear:

```
create column table calendar
( yr integer
 , period nvarchar (2) 
 , primary key (yr, period))
 
 
 insert into calendar 
 ( select year (generated_period_start) as yr
        , ABAP_NUMC( month(generated_period_start), 2) as period 
   from series_generate_date ('INTERVAL 1 MONTH', '2022-01-01', '2023-01-01'));
 

create column table data
( yr integer
 , period nvarchar (2) 
 , qty integer
 , primary key (yr, period));
 
insert into data values (2022, '01', 10);
insert into data values (2022, '02', 5);
insert into data values (2022, '04', 10);
insert into data values (2022, '05', 7);
insert into data values (2022, '09', 1);
 
 
SELECT * 
FROM CALendar A
LEFT JOIN data B
 on A.YR = B.YR
 and A.Period = B.Period
 WHERE A.Period <'10' and A.YR =2022
ORDER BY  A.period;

/*
YR      PERIOD  YR      PERIOD  QTY
2,022   01      2,022   01      10 
2,022   02      2,022   02      5  
2,022   03      ?       ?       ?  
2,022   04      2,022   04      10 
2,022   05      2,022   05      7  
2,022   06      ?       ?       ?  
2,022   07      ?       ?       ?  
2,022   08      ?       ?       ?  
2,022   09      2,022   09      1  
*/
```

The `NUMC()` function creates ABAP NUMC strings (with leading zeroes) from integers. Other than this it's pretty much the tables from OP.

The general approach is to use the `CALENDAR` table as the main driving table that establishes for which dates/periods there will be output rows.

This is outer joined with the `DATA` table, leaving "missing" rows with `NULL` in the corresponding columns.

Next, the `DATA` table is joined again, this time with `YEAR||PERIOD` combinations that are strictly smaller then the `YEAR||PERIOD` from the `CALENDAR` table. This gives us rows for **all** the previous records in `DATA`.

Next, we need to pick which of the previous rows we want to look at.
This is done via the `ROWNUM()` function and a filter to the first record.
As graphical calculation views don't support `ROWNUM()` this can be exchanged with `RANK()` - this works as long as there are no two actual `DATA` records for the same `YEAR||PERIOD` combination.

Finally, in the projection we use `COALESCE` to switch between the actual information available in `DATA` and - if that is `NULL` - the previous period information.

```
/*
CAL_YR  CAL_PER COALESCE(DAT_YR,PREV_YR)    COALESCE(DAT_PER,PREV_PER)  COALESCE(DAT_QTY,PREV_QTY)
2,022   01      2,022                       01                          10                        
2,022   02      2,022                       02                          5                         
2,022   03      2,022                       02                          5                         
2,022   04      2,022                       04                          10                        
2,022   05      2,022                       05                          7                         
2,022   06      2,022                       05                          7                         
2,022   07      2,022                       05                          7                         
2,022   08      2,022                       05                          7                         
2,022   09      2,022                       09                          1                         
*/
```

So far, so good.

The graphical calc. view for that looks like this:

[image: graphical calc view FILLUP]

As it's cumbersome to screenshoot every single node, I will include the just most important ones:

**1. CAL_DAT_PREV**

[image: CAL_DAT_PREV node]

Since only equality joins are supported in graphical calc. views we have to emulate the "larger than" join. For that, I created to calculated/constant columns `join_const` with the same value (integer `1` in this case) and joined on those.

**2. PREVS_ARE_OLDER**

[image: PREVS_ARE_OLDER node]

This is the second part of the emulated "larger than" join: this projection simply filters out the records where `cal_yr_per` is larger or equal than `prev_yr_per`. Equal values must be allowed here, since we don't want to loose records for which there is no smaller `YEAR||PERIOD` combination. Alternatively, one could insert an intial record into the `DATA` table, that is guranteed to be smaller than all other entries, e.g. `YEAR`= `0001` and `PERIOD`=`00` or something similar. If you're familiar with SAP application tables, then you've seen this approach.

By the way - for convenience reasons, I created calculated columns that combine the `YEAR` and `PERIOD` for the different tables - `cal_yr_per`, `dat_yr_per`, and `prev_yr_per`.

**3. RANK_1**

[image: RANK_1 node]

Here the rank is created for `PREV_YR_PR`, picking the first one only, and starting a new group for every new value fo `cal_yr_per`.
This value is returned via `Rank_Column`.

**4. REDUCE_PREV**

[image: REDUCE_PREV node]

The final piece of the puzzle: using a filter on `Rank_Column` = 1 we ensure to only get one "previous" row for every "calendar" row.

Also: by means of `IF(ISNULL(...), ... , ...)` we emulate `COALESCE(...)` in three calculated columns, aptly named `FILL...`.

And that's the nuts and bolts of this solution.

*"It's works on my computer!"* is probably the best I can say about it.

```
SELECT  "CAL_YR", "CAL_PERIOD"
      , "DAT_YR", "DAT_PER", "DAT_QTY"
      , "FILL_YR", "FILL_QTY", "FILL_PER" 
FROM "_SYS_BIC"."scratch/QTY_FILLUP"
ORDER BY "CAL_YR" asc, "CAL_PERIOD" asc;

/*
CAL_YR  CAL_PERIOD  DAT_YR  DAT_PER DAT_QTY FILL_YR FILL_QTY    FILL_PER
2,022   01          2,022   01      10      2,022   10          01      
2,022   02          2,022   02      5       2,022   5           02      
2,022   03          ?       ?       ?       2,022   5           02      
2,022   04          2,022   04      10      2,022   10          04      
2,022   05          2,022   05      7       2,022   7           05      
2,022   06          ?       ?       ?       2,022   7           05      
2,022   07          ?       ?       ?       2,022   7           05      
2,022   08          ?       ?       ?       2,022   7           05      
2,022   09          2,022   09      1       2,022   1           09      
2,022   10          ?       ?       ?       2,022   1           09      
2,022   11          ?       ?       ?       2,022   1           09      
2,022   12          ?       ?       ?       2,022   1           09      
*/
```

Comment: I'll get this tested later today.  I knew a rank() was going to be involved and having to materialize the rank is going to be expensive.  Were I kept falling short was thinking though how to apply it to get the value I was after  maybe it was just a bad few days of constant interruption. As to "persons that are supposedly able to maintain graphical calc. views but not SQL statement will be able to successfully maintain this is rather questionable" I hear ya.  But some of the things they done without knowing SQL have been... interesting... Usually at a cost of performance; but they work.

Comment: I can't see why this wouldn't work; but that's why we test

Comment: Once again, thanks for your time!